How to vectorize rolling average using datetime not fixed window
I have a dataframe of stock prices for around 5 years indexed on datetime that I need to get the 1 year and 6 month rolling Z score. A fixed window number for .rolling will be slightly off won't give me the exact -1year starting or -6month since the dates are only trading days, include holidays, not aways the same per year but I can't find a way besides using for loop to using relative time delta.
def rolling_zscore(prices, window, start_date, end_date):
    if window == 6:
        window = relativedelta(months=6)
        
    elif window == 12:
        window = relativedelta(years=1)

    start_date = prices.index[0] + window #cut off df that do not have enough data per window specified for rolling
    full_df = prices[start_date:]

    prices["Z Score"] = 0

    for i in full_df.index: #iterate through each row to get exact datetime difference
        temp_df = ratio.truncate(before = i - window, after=i)
        rolling_mean = temp_df.mean()[0]
        rolling_stdev = temp_df.std()[0]
        rolling_zscore = (full_df.loc[i][0] - rolling_mean)/rolling_stdev
        ratio["Z Score"][i] = rolling_zscore

    return zscore

